# Plotting grib file in Java GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools, grib

I'm fairly new to Java and GeoTools and I'm trying to plot [this grib](https://gitlab.com/datamarindo/grib_java/-/raw/master/Brest1.grb?inline=false) of meteorological data; I have the code for shapefiles, but I don't know where to go from here:

```
File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }

        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
        CachingFeatureSource cache = new CachingFeatureSource(featureSource);
        // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
        MapContent map = new MapContent();
        map.setTitle("Using cached features");
        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
        FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(cache, style);
        map.addLayer(layer);
        // Now display the map
        JMapFrame.showMap(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) world (as with most of GIS) we consider vector and raster data as fundamentally different things. So a shapefile is classed as a [vector datasource](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/index.html) and returns you a collection of features that represent a geometry and associated attributes. A raster (or [coverage](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/index.html)) is an N dimensional grid of data (where N is normally 2 but can be more), they are read in using a `GridCoverageReader` rather than a `DataStore`.

To read a grib file you need the `gt-grib` plugin covered on the [Coverage MultiDimensional](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/multidim.html) page

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-grib</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and some code like:

```
    // Selection of the NetCDF file
    File file = new File("path/to/file.grb2");

    // Creation of the NetCDF reader
    final NetCDFReader reader = new NetCDFReader(file, null);

    // It is better to surround this part of code with a try-finally construct
    // in order to avoid to leave the reader unclosed.
    try {
            // Getting the coverage names
            String[] names = reader.getGridCoverageNames();

            // Selection of the first coverage name
            String first = names[0];

            // Selection of the coverage associated to the name
            GridCoverage2D grid = reader.read(first, null);

            // Example: Get the value for the following position.
            float[] value = grid.evaluate((DirectPosition) new
                    DirectPosition2D(grid.getCoordinateReferenceSystem(), 5, 45 ), new float[1]);

    } finally {
            // Closure of the Reader
            if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                            reader.dispose();
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                            // Log the exception
                    }
            }
    }
```

There are more examples of its usage in the [`GribTest.java`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/coverage-multidim/grib/src/test/java/org/geotools/coverage/io/grib/GribTest.java) file.